# Let consider a disjoint union of intervals from $(0,1)$ such that there is no two points at distance $\frac{1}{12}$ in the union.

Tags: combinatorics

Let   consider a  disjoint    union  of  intervals from $(0,1)$   such  that   there  is  no   two  points at   distance $\frac{1}{12}$  in   the  union. Prove  that the   sum  of   the  lenght  of   the   interval  is lower than $\frac{1}{2}$. How   to   start?  Thank  you!  I  considered  two consecutive   intervals $(a,b)$  and $(c,d)$. Then $ a+ 1/12 \geq b$ and $  a+ 1/12 \leq c$

Comment: Well, each interval is at most $\frac1{12}$ long, and there must be at least a $\frac1{12}$ gap between each interval ... what should this tell you?

Comment: @DonThousand there   is  a  finite  number  of  intervals?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @DonThousand but?

Comment: If the intervals are as large as possible, then there are finitely many. If you can show that to maximize the sums of the lengths of the interval, each interval should be maximized, you'd be in good shape.

Comment: @DonThousand If    each   interval  is   maximized   then   there  are   6  interval? True?

Comment: Yup, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set of elements $x \in (0,1)$ **not** in one of the intervals

We specify a set $T$ as follows:

1. Define the subintervals $A_i \doteq (\frac{i}{12}, \frac{i+1}{12})$; $i=0,1,\ldots, 11$
2. For each $i$ even let $T \cap A_i$ be the set of points $x: x+\frac{1}{12} \in S$ and for $i$ odd let $T \cap A_i$ be the set of points $x: x-\frac{1}{12}  \in S$.

Then note the following: On the one hand, $\mu(S) = \mu(T)$. On the other hand, every point in $\cup_{i=0}^{11} A_i$ is either in $S$ or $T$.

As $\mu(\cup_{i=0}^{11} A_i)=1$ it follows that

$$1= \mu(\cup_{i=0}^{11} A_i)= \mu(S \cup T) \le \mu(S) + \mu(T) = 2\mu(S),$$

so $\mu(S)$ must be at least $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Now, if you had instead a *finite* odd-cardinality set $W$ of numbers in $(0,1)$ then there is a subset $W '$ s.t. $|W'| = \frac{|W|+1}{2} > \frac{|W|}{2}$ that satisfies the property $x \in W' \Rightarrow x+\frac{1}{12} \not \in W'$.....

Comment: Indeed partition $W$ into sets $W_1,\ldots, W_r$ for some $r$, where $a$ and $b$ are in the same $W_j$ iff $a-b = \frac{i}{12}$ for some integer $i$. Note that this partition is well-defined, and that for each $j$, at least half of the elements in $W_j$ can be put into $W'$. As $|W|$ is odd there is at least one $j$ s.t. $|W_j|$ is odd so more than half of the elements in $W_j$ can be put into $W'$ (and at least half of the elements in the other $W_l$s into $W'$) so $|W'| > |W|/2$.